# Windows 7 upgrade - deauthorize computer in iTunes - what gives?

Tags: windows-7, itunes

During my Windows 7 upgrade (from Vista) I was prompted to deauthorize my computer in iTunes. I did, but why did I have to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to play DRM protected content, iTunes "authorizes" your particular installation of iTunes to play certain protected files (see the [Apple Knowledge Base](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1420)).  DRM protected content can only be played on a certain number (5) of "authorized" devices.  When you upgrade to Windows 7, Windows recognizes that that authorization is not going to be carried over to the new OS, so it prompts you to de-authorize your content, so you can re-authorize it when you have finished the upgrade without losing one of your authorized devices.  Just another nicety of the Windows 7 experience.